# ruby installation with rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I installed Ruby with rbenv. When trying to install Rails using `gem install rails` I get:

```
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

I suspect that there is a conflict with my Ruby versions.

`rbenv local` and `rbenv global` are set to 1.9.3-p327, but if I type `ruby -v` I get "ruby 1.8.7".

How can I change this to 1.9.3?

```
echo $PATH:
/usr/local/opt/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: The problem isn't a conflict with Ruby gems. What does your PATH look like? Enter `echo $PATH` and append that to your question.

Comment: Which gem is failing? Each time there is a failure there's a reference to a particular build log with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`rbenv local 1.9.3-p327`

and then

`rbenv rehash` just to be sure.

Also, you can set 1.9.3-p327 as the default with:

`rbenv global 1.9.3-p327`

Comment: Had a similar problem. Not sure how but on a clean install `rbenv local` was set to a version never installed. Updating it solved the issue.